# How to start an application on Windows after a Jenkins build

Tags: windows, maven, jenkins-pipeline

I am want to start a (Spring Boot) application on a Windows server after it was built by Maven, which was started by Jenkins.

I am able to build in Jenkins using `mvn spring-boot:run`, which automatically starts the application, but this results in a Jenkins build process that never finishes. I want the application to start and to continue running while the Jenkins build finishes.

Also, when I need to stop and restart the application, I need to

1. stop/kill the Jenkins build process
2. look up the application's Java process that was started via the Windows Task Manager and kill that as well, since the application keeps running in a separate process.

There must be a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Jenkins build pipeline, it is easy to build the application and run the application. You can follow this link to get an idea. Although this link is unix system, you can modify to do it for Windows.

https://vindytechblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/04/jenkins-configurations-to-build-and-deploy-wso2-carbon-application/

Also, you can mention the command in the last pipeline about what to do after building the application. Besides, you have to first stop already running the spring boot application instance.

You can also refer below the link about the pipeline script.
https://www.baeldung.com/jenkins-pipelines

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This pointed me in the right direction. 

Comment: Hi Sambit. I've done so, but got this warning: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Thanks again...!